# How can I find multiple files in multiple subdirectories?

Tags: bash, find

I need to find a list of files in multiple subdirectories and save the path of each file in a txt file. I have all the filenames in a list in `filenames.txt`.
I am trying to do this:

```
while read -r fname; do
    find . -name "$fname" > paths.txt
done < filenames.txt
```

Is this correct? It seems to take quite more time than I was expecting, even though I know I have a lot of subdirectories (200k) to search. Are there better ways of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Filenames may contain newline characters. Can we assume that none of your filenames contain newline characters?

Comment: @Quasimodo each filename is on a new line. I don't know if this means that there is a newline character after each filename, but I suppose so. How can I check?

Comment: That is what I meant, filenames with no newline, but after each filename a newline. (TBH I think it would be impossible to have filenames in a text file if we allowed all the unusual but allowed characters to be part of the filenames.) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You are running find multiple times, once for each line in filenames.txt - that can be the bottleneck.

You can try to reverse the process - first find all files, then compare it to the files from the list. Something like

```
find * > allfiles.txt
grep -f filenames.txt allfiles.txt
```

Comment: `find *` will not output any files that start with a `.` such as `.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
find . -print0 | gawk -F/ '
   ARGIND == 1 {selected[$0]; next}
   $NF in selected' filenames.txt RS='\0' -
```

That is, have `find` reports *all* the files, but do the filtering with `gawk` using a hash table built from the contents of `filenames.txt`.

That way, you run `find` only once and do the matching in a more efficient manner.

That assumes `filenames.txt` is meant to contain a list of literal filenames, not a list of wildcard patterns (`find`'s `-name` expects a wildcard pattern, not a literal filename).